# What is the difference between a Nikon  "Micro" lens and a "Macro" lens?

Tags: nikon, macro, terminology

When it comes to **macro photography** and Nikon, what is the difference between a **Micro** and a **Macro** [Nikkor] lens?

Is the answer as simple as to say that Nikon uses Micro in its nomenclature for its macro photography lenses?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Historically, "macro" has been reserved for lenses that can make 1:1 or larger reproductions - microscope territory.

Nikon makes (or made) lenses for microphotography that they call Macro-Nikkors. Their engineers therefore decided to call the common-or-garden lenses that only go down to 1:1 for "Micro-Nikkors". [See the discussion on Nikon's site here](http://imaging.nikon.com/history/nikkor/25/index.htm), and on [Bjørn Rørslett's site here](http://www.naturfotograf.com/lens_spec.html).

Nikon doesn't have an equivalent to Canons 65mm MP-E lens, which can go down to 5:1, but if they did, it would probably be a "Macro-Nikkor" as opposed to a "Micro-Nikkor".

Answer (score 5):

Yup, the answer is that simple.  In Nikon-ese they use the term 'Micro' to mean 1:1 reproduction - which is Macro to the rest of the world.

Comment: It's worth noting that ["micro"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/micro) (ie: very small) is probably more appropriate than ["macro"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/macro) (ie: very large), in the same way that we talk about "microscopes"

Comment: Eh, po-tay-toe, po-tah-toe. You're bringing the 'micro' world into the 'macro' world.  Either name works.